# Erroron reactredux router

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-router

I'm using this code to create route redux router

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import Calendar from '../calendar/calendar'
import Cards from '../cards/cards'

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory)
const App= () => {
return <div>
    <h2>start</h2>
    <a href="/calendar">calendar</a>
    <a href="/cards">cards</a>
</div>
}

const store = createStore(
 combineReducers({
   routing: routerReducer
 })
)


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
{ /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="calendar" component={Calendar}/>
    <Route path="cards" component={Cards}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('mount')
)
```

I'm getting this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined"

I'm trying to implement router redux on app redux
Thanks

Carlos Vieira

Comment: I'm following this link https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Comment: you have to show the code where you call `getState`

Comment: where i put get state ? i'm just following the code lines of the link under https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: can you show us the code where you created the store?

Comment: i'm following the website above and i create the store with
const store = createStore(
 combineReducers({
   routing: routerReducer
 })
)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided it is difficult to tell exactly what your problem is, however if you are trying to use `React-Router` you may want to begin by changing the links to mirror its use.

Try replacing:

```
<a href="/calendar">calendar</a>
<a href="/cards">cards</a>
```

With this:

```
<Link to="/calendar">calender</Link>
<Link to="/cards">cards</Link>
```

And import Link from React-Router by placing this at the top of your file:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Link } from 'react-router'
```

If this does nothing to solve your issue, and you post where you are attempting to initialize the `state` and perhaps also attempting to `setState` you may receive more help with that error.

Comment: Hello, thanks by your answer, to be honest i'm not initialising a state i just follow the web site above of react redux router and implement the code...
it should work, but i dont know what is happening.
I will attempt your changes... i will give a feedback.
Thanks Carlos Vieira